# Sidebar overlapping the content and footer

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a illustration here to best describe my problem
[image]
 
The Sidebar is overlapping my Content and Footer whenever the Content has only small items.
In my **_layout** I'm calling my sidebar like this

```
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div id="header">          
        <div id="menucontainer">
             <ul id="nav">
               MENUTABS
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">   
    <div id = "sidebar">
    @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar"))
    {
        @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)

    }
    else { 
       <p>Currently Unavailable, Sorry for the inconvinience</p>
    }
        </div>

        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="copyright">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

then in my **View** I'm calling it like this

```
 @section SideBar
   {
    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Post");}
   }
```

Here's my CSS

```
.page {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#main 
{
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#sidebar
{
    float:left;
    margin:200px 10px -30px 10px;
    padding:10px -10px -10px 10px;
    width:235px;
    height:auto;
    border: solid 2px black;
    background-color:#9acbba;    
}

footer, 
#footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

Please help me figure out guys what's the cause of this problem. Thanks T_T

Comment: Have you cleared your float?

Comment: try adding <br style="clear:both;"> at the bottom of the element that contains the left nav and the content.

Comment: the float in the #sidebar? you mean remove/delete it? when I remove it content moves under the sidebar. T_T

Comment: after the sidebar add what user irregularexpressions said.

Comment: Ok, drop the float. floats are outside the normal flow.

Comment: @irregularexpressions could you post your answer I think you understood my problem. I'm a little confuse how to do your suggestion.. :)

Comment: A fiddle would be nice :) seems to be a css problem though - And the markup/css seems to be pretty bad, it seems that you need to stucture your website more than you have done.. why the margin? margin:200px 10px -30px 10px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the thing is this is really simple tbh... nearly all your markup was wrong but here you have a working frame for your website see **[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YymEd/2/)**

**THE HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div id="main">   
        <div id="header">          
            <div id="menucontainer">
                 <ul id="nav">
                   MENUTABS
                 </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
             @if (IsSectionDefined("SideBar")) {
                   @RenderSection("SideBar", required: false)

             } else { 
                   <p>Currently Unavailable, Sorry for the inconvinience</p>
             }
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="copyright">FOOTER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**THE CSS**

```
.page {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main 
{
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    width:940px;
}
#header {
    width:900px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background: yellow;
}
#content {
    width: 641px;
    background: blue;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
#sidebar
{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    width:215px;
    height:auto;
    border: solid 2px black;
    background-color:red;    
} 
#footer {
    background-color: white;
    color: #999;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Well you also have a point dude. Thanks for sharing your ideas. I'll consider your post as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should `float` also the `div` wrapper of `#sidebar` and i'm guesting that is the `#main`

```
#main 
{
   float:left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;

}
```

PLS... see the demo

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/YpwMh/1/)